# Force Stop android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Help me!
I need the source code to force stop an Android application programmatically.
I already tried

`Process.killProcess(int pid))`

but it didn't work

Thank You.

Comment: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to stop a process from java

1.kill directly

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

2.send `SIG_KILL`

```
Process.sendSignal(Process.myPid(), Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
```

3.the unfriendly way, terminate the vm

```
System.exit(0);
```